# .htaccess Rewrite index.php back to directory where index.php is located

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a directory of `localhost/testing/pages/index.php`

How do I redirect user to `localhost/testing/pages/` whenever they enter `localhost/testing/pages/index.php` with `index.php` extension?

I have tried to use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
Rewrite %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
```

but this does not work.

Thanks!

Comment: Because `index.php` exists and `Rewrite %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` will only rewrite if the request is *not* a file that exists. You need to put a rule higher up that explicitly matches `index.php` and rewrites.

Comment: what do you mean by `put a rule higher up`? any examples please?

Comment: Above `Rewrite %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
```